# Combo-box multi-selection to display the selected Items in a Text box in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox

I have a combo box on a form that does allow multi item selections. It displays over 200 different roles that need to be assigned to a user. A user can have multiple roles. I want to display those selected items in an unbound Text box.

I am trying to figure out how to write the vba code to capture all the selections. I did a simple IF statement and it works if one item is selected. However, when there is multiple items selected the display in the Text box is null.

Here is what I have so far any help is greatly appreciated. `cboRequestedRoles` is the name of my combo box and `txt_SelectedRoles` is the name of my text box. I am using MS Access DB 2016 on a windows 10 platform.

```
 If Not IsNull(Me.cboRequestedRoles) Then
     Me.txt_SelectedRoles = Me.cboRequestedRoles.Column(2)
 Else
     Me.txt_SelectedRoles.Value = ""
 End If
```

[image: Disgn View of CBOBox]
[image: Form View of CBOBox]
[image: CBOBox Open]
[image: CBOBox with multiple selections]

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Do you really mean a combo box with multi selection or maybe a list box?

Comment: It is a combo box and yes it is allowing me to select multiple items i will work on getting a screen shot for this post.

Comment: I have attached some images to help. let me know if there is anything else i can provide. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```vb
Dim result As String

With Me.cboRequestedRoles
    Dim index As Long
    For index = 0 To .ItemsSelected.Count - 1
        result = result & _
                 .Column(1, index) & _
                 ": " & _
                 .Column(2, index) & _
                 vbNewLine
    Next index
End With

Me.txt_SelectedRoles.Value = result
```

You can edit it yourself regarding which columns you want to be in the result.

Comment: @BrianBlanton: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the ComboBox is not working properly even in 2016. It took me a bit to figure it out and the only way of doing it was doing it this way. The itemsSelection wouldn't state that there were nothing there and the selection.count was equal to 0. I don't know what is wrong with it. So I used the value as an array as it is in the coding and then broke it up in to each array equaling the result. The vbNewLine is only used when separating the strings so why have it on the end.

```
Dim result As String
result = ""
With Me.cboRequestedRoles

    Dim index As Long

    For index = 0 To ubound(.value)

        if index > 0 then
             result = result & vbNewLine
        endif

        result = result & .value(index)
    Next index
End With

Me.txt_SelectedRoles.Value = result
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Unhandled Exception

```
Dim result As String
With Me.cboRequestedRoles
    Dim index As Long
    For index = 0 To .ItemsSelected.Count - 1
        result = result & _
                 .Column(1, index) & _
                 ": " & _
                 .Column(2, index) & _
                 vbNewLine
    Next index
End With

Me.txt_SelectedRoles.Value = result
```

this was answered by 
answered 6 hours ago

Unhandled Exception